# setting root hints in PowerDNS does NOT work

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, internal-dns, powerdns, powerdns-recursor

I would like to create a fully DNS hierarchy on my own for a project. Here is my setup:

- BIND9 for the Root Nameserver "." (10.0.2.15)
- BIND9 Authoritative Nameserver for the domain "dnslab"
- PowerDNS as a Recursive Resolver (10.0.2.10)
- All software is installed on separate VMs running Ubuntu server 22.04

Content of my root hints (=local_root.hints) file:

```
.               3600000      NS    nameserver.
nameserver.     3600000      A     10.0.2.15
```

Content of the PowerDNS config:

```
# defines address to listen on
local-address=10.0.2.10
allow-from=10.0.2.0/24

#################################
# hint-file     If set, load root hints from this file
#
hint-file=/etc/powerdns/local_root.hints

#################################
# include-dir   Include *.conf files from this directory
#
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/recursor.d

#################################
# lua-config-file       More powerful configuration options
#
lua-config-file=/etc/powerdns/recursor.lua

#################################
# dnssec        DNSSEC mode: off/process-no-validate/process (default)/log-fail/validate
#
dnssec=off

#################################
# dnssec-log-bogus      Log DNSSEC bogus validations
#
# dnssec-log-bogus=no

#################################
# config-dir    Location of configuration directory (recursor.conf)
#
config-dir=/etc/powerdns

#################################
```

My Query to the PowerDNS resolver and its answer:

```
dig @10.0.2.10 dnslab

; <<>> DiG 9.19.19-1-Debian <<>> @10.0.2.10 dnslab
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 61832
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dnslab.                                IN      A

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.2.10#53(10.0.2.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 02 06:00:23 EST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35
```

If I want to query my root directly, I get the same answer (=SERVFAIL):

```
dig @10.0.2.10 . 

; <<>> DiG 9.19.19-1-Debian <<>> @10.0.2.10 .
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 39738
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.                              IN      A

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.2.10#53(10.0.2.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 02 06:10:43 EST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 28
```

I also made the following 2 observations:

1. I used two different recursive resolvers (BIND9-based and Unbound-based) in same setup: In both cases I get correct name resolution => delegation etc. works (problem is at resolver level)
2. If I set the content of the local_root.hints file to a legit Root server, resolution works:

```
.                        3600000      NS    A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     198.41.0.4
```

Is it possible that PowerDNS makes some checks to determine if the root nameservers are legit?

I am really confused, can somebody help out here please!

Comment: Maybe this article is helpful https://lantian.pub/en/article/modify-website/selfhost-dns-root-server.lantian